# Stack traces with react-navigation in React Native don't show location in

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The stack traces I am getting from React Native in the iOS simulator are not giving useful line numbers in my application. I have made it pretty far even so, however sometimes it can be quite difficult to find the source of the exception.

Is there a way to get better information?

A sample stack trace is below. StackView is my React functional view. SceneView is from react-navigation.

```
Error: firebase.firestore().collection().where(_, _, *) 'value' argument expected.

This error is located at:
    in StackView (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:190)
    ...
```

This is an excerpt from SceneView.tsx:

```
          {'component' in screen && screen.component !== undefined ? (
            // @ts-ignore
            <screen.component navigation={navigation} route={route} /> // THIS LINE
          ) : 'children' in screen && screen.children !== undefined ? (
            // @ts-ignore
            screen.children({ navigation, route })
          ) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

**My code:**

```
static getBy(appLanguage, arrayContains) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.unSubscribe = collection
            .where('language', '==', appLanguage)
            .where('code', 'in', arrayContains)
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const behaviorChange = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((profile) => {
                    const item = profile.data();
                    const { icon } = item;
                    behaviorChange.push({
                        id: profile.id,
                        ...item,
                    });
                });
                resolve(behaviorChange);
            });
    });
}

// ERROR 
this.getBy(arrayContains);
```

My mistake was not sending the first variable (appLanguage) as a parameter.